# Как правильно получить координаты и масштаб?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

У меня вопрос:
Я правильно получаю координаты x,y?
Как сделать если x,y равны (0.5, 0.5), то центр картинки будет размещаться в правом верхнем углу синей области?

Если scale = 1, картинка будет занимать всю поверхность синей области. 
Если картинка квадратная и scale = 1, то картинка будет по высоте занимать всю синею область, а по ширине вылезать немного за пределы.
Соответственно уменьшая scale картинка будет уменьшаться на синей области, если scale = 0 значит картинку вообще не будет видно, а если 0.5 то картинка = половинка синей области!

Как такое сделать с масштабом?

Вот я набросал свой пример на котором я остановился, и больше ничего в голову не лезет:

```
<body>
<div id="coords">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="scale">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="block">
<div id="joystick">
<div id="mover" style="
background: url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/JMJXvsCLu6s/mqdefault.jpg) 100% 100% no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

[Ссылка на codepen.io](http://codepen.io/asvis/pen/bwLKdx)

Спасибо!

Comment: Мне кажется я Вас понял :) Вы хотите чтобы при масштабе правого нижнего угла верхний левый оставался в той же позиции и чтобы при масштабе сохранялись пропорции?

Comment: @OlmerDale Смотрите, у меня в примере есть значение scale, Первый вопрос: Я его правильно нашел??, Второй вопрос: как сделать так если центр картинки находиться в правом верхнем углу то значение x,y = 0.5,0.5?

Answer (score 2):

> Масштаб - `scale`, это всего-лишь отношение коэффициента к длине стороны.

Если предположить что исходная сторона ровна `360`, а текущая `90`, то найти масштаб можно так -

```
90 / 360 = 0.25
```

И наоборот, если известны текущие размеры стороны, пусть будут так же `90` и масштаб `.25`, то исходные значения можно узнать -

```
90 / .25 = 360 // исходный размер стороны
```

Надеюсь понятно объяснил чтобы справится с масштабом самостоятельно.

Ну а дальше все так же просто. Находите центр ручки, размер которой `360x360` и центр фигуры, размер которой `720х720`, в которую эта ручка должна быть вписана. В стартовом состоянии маштаб ручки будет `1х1`, а длина между центрами будет `0`.

Теперь представьте что Вы переместили ручку центром в правый верхний угол и тем самым масштаб должен стать `0.5х0.5`. Поэтому нужно найти длину между двумя точкам, она же будет максимальным расстоянием от центра, пусть эта длина будет `500`. Это означает что переместив ручку из исходного положения на `500px` её размер с `360x360` изменится до `180x180`, то есть её масштаб уменьшится в два раза. Находим это так -

```
0.5 * 500 = 0.001 // это коэффициент масштаба к длине 500
```

Теперь все что нам осталось, это при драге ручки находить длину между её центром и центром фигуры в которою она вписана, умножать её на `0.001` и вычитать из `1`, так как у нас происходит удаление от центра и полученное значение будет значением масштаба ручки.

Comment: стороны это ширина и высота?

Comment: да,  `width` и `height`. вы же джостик хотите сделать?

Comment: хочу сделать так: если масштаб #mover = 1 то он должен собой закрыть джойстика(#joystick) тоесть по размерам стать как джойстик, а если масштаб 2 то соответственно в два раза больше